# Canvas: Simulating camera with scale and rotation

Tags: javascript, math, canvas

I've created a camera object, in which it's position acts as the center of the screen. The camera allows scaling and rotation. So basically what I've done is I've translated the center of the canvas to the origin, applied the scale, then the rotation, now I need to know what kind of tricky maths I need to use to translate it back to the center, this is my code so far:

```
__Stage__.prototype.__cameraTransform = function() {
    var canvas = this.__canvas;
    var cam = this.camera;
    var context = this.__canvasContext;

    var cx = canvas.width/2;
    var cy = canvas.height/2;
    context.translate(-cx,-cy);

    var scale = {x: canvas.width/cam.width, y: canvas.height/cam.height};
    context.scale(scale.x,scale.y);

    var rotation = Math.PI*2 - (cam.rotation%(Math.PI*2));
    context.rotate(-rotation);

    context.translate(/*What translation to get the point back in the center*/);
}
```

Comment: As an extra, if you remove the rotation bit, I managed to get it back to the center after just scaling with this line:

context.translate(cx*(2/scale.x-1),cy*(2/scale.y-1));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing is you might want to save the context or reset it for some reason.
For the save/restore thing, i can't guess how you would handle it, and a reset is done with :

```
function resetTransform() {
    c.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
}
```

Second thing is you didn't mention where the camera was looking, i assumed it looks at `centerX`, `centerY`.

Third thing is you'll want to avoid changing the aspect ratio while scaling, so rather compute the canvas's aspect ratio and have the camera view height = camera view width * canvas ratio.

Object.defineProperty allows to define a property on your objects, so you can do it in a clean way :

```
// at the global level, after document loaded
//    OR where you handle the canvas
var canvasRatio = canvas.height / canvas.width;

//... in your camera constructor 
Object.defineProperty(this, 'height', {
    get: function () {
        return canvasRatio * this.width ;
    },
    set: function (val) {},
    enumerable: true
});
```

Then you might want to cache the canvas size to avoid DOM access during your game.

For your rotation computation, i didn't get it but no need to clamp in [0,2*PI] or like : just use any radian value that you have (initialized at 0).

So now for your camera, the code is now the following :

```
__Stage__.prototype.__cameraTransform = function() {
    var canvas = this.__canvas;
    var cam = this.camera;
    var context = this.__canvasContext;
   // O. reset ??
   resetTransform();
    //
    var cx = this.__canvasWidth/2;
    var cy = this.__canvasHeight/2;
    // 1 .  translate  to the middle of the canvas
    context.translate(cx,cy);
    // 2. scale
    var scale = this.__canvasWidth/cam.width;
    context.scale(scale,scale);
    // 3. translate to where the camera looks
    context.translate(-cam.centerX,-cam.centerY);
    // 4. rotate
    context.rotate(cam.rotation);    
}
```

Comment: Huh, this is an extremely simple solution and it works. Thank you kind sir!